# REGEX minimum of 8 digits or null

Tags: jquery, regex

can anyone help me of my promblem. What i want is to create a regex that accept 8 digits and above or null string.

Here is my code:

```
/^(?:(.+)?\d+(.+)?){8}$/
```

My code accept 8 digits and above but not a null string.

Can someone help me. Thanks

Comment: please clarify your need more....

Comment: When you say "null", do you mean "an empty string"?

Comment: And how would you logically match a null string? LOL It defies logic :D

Comment: Could you provide some testdata.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean at least 8 digits or an empty string, this would work:

```
^((\D*\d\D*){8,}|)$
```

Zero or more non-digit characters `\D*` followed by a digit `\d` followed by zero or more non-digits, 8 or more times. Or the start of the string followed by the end (an empty string).

Testing it out:

```
/^((\D*\d\D*){8,}|)$/.test("")
true
/^((\D*\d\D*){8,}|)$/.test("a1b2c3d4")
false
/^((\D*\d\D*){8,}|)$/.test("a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8")
true
/^((\D*\d\D*){8,}|)$/.test("a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j")
true
```

Comment: what i mean is to create regex that accept 8 digits and above or a null string.

Comment: @user3351036 does this not do what you want then? If not, it would be helpful to add some examples to your question.

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work:

```
/^(?:(.+)?\d+(.+)?){8}|null$/
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you, try this:

```
/^(?:(.+)?\d+(.+)?){8}|$/
```